# How to install UML plugin in Eclipse Juno

Tags: uml, eclipse-juno

May be this question has been asked several times. But i am not getting exact solution. So, i have post this question here..
I try hard to install UML2 Tool SDK plugin in Eclipse Juno. I have try to install by following steps.

- help -> Install New Software
- Add URL as "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/ganymede"
- I have select UML2 Tools SDK (Incubation) under Models and Model Development.
- I have click next, then i get error like this.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: UML2 Tools SDK (Incubation)
>   0.8.0.v200809231457 (org.eclipse.uml2tools.sdk.feature.group 0.8.0.v200809231457)   Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (epp.package.jee
>   1.5.1.20120917-1257)   Missing requirement: OCL 2.0 Binding for Ecore 1.3.0.v200905271400 (org.eclipse.ocl.ecore 1.3.0.v200905271400) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore [2.5.0,2.6.0)' but it could not
>   be found   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       EMF Ecore 2.8.3.v20130125-0546 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.8.3.v20130125-0546)
>       EMF Ecore 2.7.0.v20120127-1122 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.7.0.v20120127-1122)
>       EMF Ecore 2.8.1.v20120911-0500 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.8.1.v20120911-0500)
>       EMF Ecore 2.8.0.v20120606-0717 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.8.0.v20120606-0717)
>       EMF Ecore 2.4.2.v200902171115 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.4.2.v200902171115)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (epp.package.jee 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
>       To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.5.1.20120917-1257]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Workbench Model 0.10.1.v20120523-1955 (org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench 0.10.1.v20120523-1955)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore [2.6.0,3.0.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Object Constraint Language (OCL) 2.0 Compatibility API 1.1.101.v200808291106 (org.eclipse.emf.ocl 1.1.101.v200808291106)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.ocl.ecore [1.1.0,2.0.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Object Constraint Language (OCL) 2.0 Compatibility API 1.1.101.v200901271800 (org.eclipse.emf.ocl 1.1.101.v200901271800)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.ocl.ecore [1.1.0,2.0.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group
>   1.5.1.20120917-1257)
>       To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: OCL 2.0 Binding for Ecore 1.2.1.v200807301850 (org.eclipse.ocl.ecore 1.2.1.v200807301850)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore [2.4.0,2.5.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Platform 4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group
>   4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO)
>       To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.2.1.v20120814-120134-7IAPA8BrHQicS-rjP0GbqK780kMy]   Cannot satisfy
>   dependency:
>       From: Eclipse RCP 4.2.1.v20120814-120134-7IAPA8BrHQicS-rjP0GbqK780kMy (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group
>   4.2.1.v20120814-120134-7IAPA8BrHQicS-rjP0GbqK780kMy)
>       To: org.eclipse.ui.workbench [3.103.1.v20120906-120042]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Workbench 3.103.1.v20120906-120042 (org.eclipse.ui.workbench 3.103.1.v20120906-120042)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench 0.9.1   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: UML2 Diagramming (Incubation) 0.8.1.v200809231457 (org.eclipse.uml2.diagram.feature.group 0.8.1.v200809231457)
>       To: org.eclipse.uml2.diagram.statemachine [0.8.1.v200809231457]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: UML2 State Machine Diagram Plugin (Incubation) 0.8.1.v200809231457 (org.eclipse.uml2.diagram.statemachine 0.8.1.v200809231457)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.ocl 0.0.0   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: UML2 Tools SDK (Incubation) 0.8.0.v200809231457 (org.eclipse.uml2tools.sdk.feature.group 0.8.0.v200809231457)
>       To: org.eclipse.uml2.diagram.feature.group [0.8.1.v200809231457]

I hope you will provide a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I should use `"download.eclipse.org/releases/juno"` as a URL for Eclipse Juno. Now it is working fine.